# How to get the state for a given revision for a list of IDs in Envers

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a project that is using Hibernate Envers to store audit info. Now I have a list of Ids and a revision number and I would like to get the information for the entities in that id list for the given revision.

**Is it possible to do so?**

My research led me into the AuditReader.getQuery() for which I can create a query forEntitiesAtRevision and so on, but I am not able to send an ID to select the entities I would like.

The problems is that if I can't do that, I would have to make one query per entity, which would cause thousands of requests (I have a list of 1000 ids), or get every entity and query on the Java side, which may also not be so good (I have many entities).
Because of that, I may decide to write my own query, something I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use `AuditEntity.id().in(collectionOfIds)` as the constraint for the query.